# Are HTTP requests that differ only in order of parameters equivalent?

Tags: http, parameters

Are the following two HTTP requests equivolent?

`mySite.com/my/service?foo=bar&hello=world`

`mySite.com/my/service?hello=world&foo=bar`

I presume there is a standard that defines this. If so, what is it?

Comment: @user2864740 If you make that an answer with the relevant quotes I will accept :)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100927/two-identical-urls-but-different-order-in-parameters-duplicated-content

Comment: Whoops. It does not appear to be 'directly' covered by the URL/URI as they defer it with "The query component is a string of information to be interpreted by the resource." Probably in the [HTTP RFCs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230) then.

Comment: If their are not covered from the RFCs, the order isn't relevant

Comment: Hmm, the closest I can find is [RFC3968, Section 6](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-6) but it is fairly vague and is not HTTP-specific. I could not find the definition of "equivalent requests" (which form the fundamental basis of caching) in the RFC72--s although it is mentioned several times.

Comment: @lifeisfoo Not covered in the URI RFCs (which go on the be vague about equivalency) - which defers it to the 'interpreted by resource' and thus HTTP itself. I was trying to make a case for equivalency (or lack of) based on if such are cache-equivalent, but have not been able to find a definitive reference either way ..

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) has a section 3.4 covering the Query component of an URI, however nothing is said on how to interpret order and duplicate fields.

In fact, it's very backend dependent. In practice, the order is generally not relevant as the query is generally parsed into a dictionary that provides indexed access to each component of the query by key (and not the position).

The order is only relevant in those cases where the comparison is run lexicographically. To be honest, this is a very rare case and I'd consider such implementation close to be buggy (as really nowadays is general consensus that the order of the query fields should be considered irrelevant).

Comment: [How] Is caching affected? That is the intersection of how clients and the servers (and any proxies?) agree on if the resources are 'equivalent'.

Comment: I asked this because I'm currently working with angular httpbackend and it is saying the two are not equivalent

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I would argue the only 'guaranteed' way to ensure they are treated equivalent is if they are string-equal (after URI normalization); this - a singular canonical 'key', between requests for the same resource - is definitely the most implemented method, even if the specification does not mandate it.

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, caching is affected in this way: Imagine that a server cache receives the request `uri?a=1&b=2`. Should it return the cached result of a previous request `uri?b=2&a=1` ? This is the kernel of the OP.